# Licence Key difference between AGPL-3 and LGPL-3 for Odoo manifest File

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, odoo-9, odoo-10

What is the different between  **"AGPL-3"** and **"LGPL-3"** for odoo menifiest file descriptor ?

Which cases we are using **AGPL-3** and **LGPL-3** license for our Odoo customized modules ?

Comment: [Licensing questions are off-topic on SO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/335060/will-licensing-questions-become-on-topic-once-programmers-se-changes-scope). It may be better asked on https://opensource.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because license questions are off-optic for StackOverflow

Answer (score 2):

This is from *Odoo 10 Essentials* :

> The LGPL is more permissive and allows commercial derivative work,
>   without the need to share the corresponding source code. The AGPL is a
>   stronger open source licence, and requires derivate work and service
>   hosting to share their source code.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for your answer Is it the same for OpenERP V7, Odoo 8,Odoo9 and Odoo 10 ?